# No Delete button when editing an item in Magento Grid

Tags: magento

I've successfully created my first admin grid. It works fine when adding a new item. However, when I want to edit an item, strangely, the <kbd>DELETE</kbd> button is missing. Even worse, when I click the <kbd>SAVE</kbd> button, it creates a new item instead of saving the current item. What have I done wrong?

I'm not sure what file to look at, thus I don't know which code must be posted here. If I put all the code from all files, it will be too much. Please advise.

Update: Not sure why, but now the <kbd>SAVE</kbd> button doesn't recreate any more. So I can edit an item peacefully. However, the <kbd>DELETE</kbd> button is still missing.

Comment: maybe you can put some links containing your codes, pretty sure what you need to post is your controller, blocks containing edit.php, form.php

Answer (score 11):

*Late in the game, but hopefully this will help a Googler.*

Is your `_objectId` property correctly set to the corresponding parameter in the URL?

`$this->_objectId = 'id';`

Where ID refers to this part of the URL:

/module/adminhtml_controller/edit/**id**/1/

See the parent class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container::__construct`:

```
...
$objId = $this->getRequest()->getParam($this->_objectId);

        if (! empty($objId)) {
            $this->_addButton('delete', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Delete'),
                'class'     => 'delete',
                'onclick'   => 'deleteConfirm(\''. Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Are you sure you want to do this?')
                    .'\', \'' . $this->getDeleteUrl() . '\')',
            ));
        }
...
```

We can see that if `$objId` is empty, no delete button will be added.

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks +1

Comment: Good one +1 from me :)

Comment: works fine for the delete, and now I understand that id parameter that I did not understand before. Unfortunately when editing save button goes to blank page and saves are not stored.

Comment: @Alex do you have developer mode turned on? You probably have an error  in your controller, maybe a memory exhaustion error. Turn it on to get more details, or examine your web server error log.

Answer (score 4):

After struggling around, the culprit was because I put parent::__construct(); at the top (right after the __construct() method. Instead, it should be put AFTER the $this->_controller line. Geezz...

Comment: In my case it was the other way around.

Comment: The position of parent::__construct(); also caused me the same issue

Answer (score 1):

***Remove or rename add new save continue delete button from magento admin
If you don’t want to show the ‘Add New’ button in the Grid. The Add New button is present in top right corner of Grid Page.

Rename ‘Add New’ button

Here are the steps to rename the ‘Add New’ text to anything you required (for example, ‘Add Report’):-

- Go to YourNamespace -> YourModule -> Block -> Adminhtml -> YourFile.ph`enter code here`p
- Add the following code in the constructor of this file:-

  $this->*addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('yourmodulename')->_*('Add Report');

**Remove ‘Add New’ button**
Here are the steps to remove the ‘Add New’ button:-

- Go to YourNamespace -> YourModule -> Block -> Adminhtml -> YourFile.php
- Add the following code in the constructor of this file (it should be just below the call to parent constructor):-

  parent::__construct();
  $this->_removeButton('add');

**In edit.php**

```
parent::__construct();
$this->_removeButton('delete');
$this->_removeButton('save');
$this->_removeButton('back');
```

**in grid.php**

```
parent::__construct();
$this->_removeButton('add');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try on your Grid.php:

```
    public function getRowUrl($row){
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/form', array('id' => $row->getId()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've put such function already except it refers to "edit" instead of "form". Anyway, I tried your suggestion but the result is ever worse. I got 404 error. So I put back my original function.